# Validity of alarm upon application update

Tags: android, alarmmanager, updates

Say that one of my Services set an alarm, and now updates for the application were installed.

Is it guaranteed that my alarm will fire?

If not, can I add an event listener for updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should intercept install, remove and replace broadcasts and reinstantiate your alarms there.

The actions are:

```
ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED
ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED
```

Check [this link](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1335/)

Comment: I don't think you will get the Intent if your app has been removed, because your BroadcastReceiver is not installed anymore

Comment: Right. Changed my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alarms are preserved across updates. I can at least verify that on Android 4.0.

It also works on Android 2.2. I would assume this just works.